# How does GHC recognize that a thread is BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, ghc

If a thread waits on an [`MVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-MVar.html#t:MVar) that doesn't have a possible producer, GHC is usually smart enough to throw [`BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar) and kill the thread. How is this detection implemented?

Does it check that all references to an `MVar` are from threads that are waiting on it, or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It [uses the garbage collector](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/9d299253e29558b7d18e6643e1a84fb2bbbecfe5/libraries/base/Control/Concurrent.hs#L643).

From Control.Concurrent:

> GHC attempts to detect when threads are deadlocked using the garbage
>   collector.  A thread that is not reachable (cannot be found by
>   following pointers from live objects) must be deadlocked, and in this
>   case the thread is sent an exception.  The exception is either
>   'BlockedIndefinitelyOnMVar', 'BlockedIndefinitelyOnSTM',
>   'NonTermination', or 'Deadlock', depending on the way in which the
>   thread is deadlocked.
>
> Note that this feature is intended for debugging, and should not be
>   relied on for the correct operation of your program.  There is no
>   guarantee that the garbage collector will be accurate enough to detect
>   your deadlock, and no guarantee that the garbage collector will run in
>   a timely enough manner.  Basically, the same caveats as for finalizers
>   apply to deadlock detection.
>
> There is a subtle interaction between deadlock detection and
>   finalizers (as created by 'Foreign.Concurrent.newForeignPtr' or the
>   functions in "System.Mem.Weak"): if a thread is blocked waiting for a
>   finalizer to run, then the thread will be considered deadlocked and
>   sent an exception.  So preferably don't do this, but if you have no
>   alternative then it is possible to prevent the thread from being
>   considered deadlocked by making a 'StablePtr' pointing to it.  Don't
>   forget to release the 'StablePtr' later with 'freeStablePtr'.